# Wrap __LINE__ in to single quotes

Tags: gnu, m4

How can I wrap LINE and FILE macros in M4 to display '4' or "4". I want it to be ready for output to the console. I am using C++ for this.

Comment: Do you want to wrap the macro, or the replacement text of the macro?

Comment: @KerrekSB the replacement macro in a quote.

Comment: In what way are you using C++?  Do you mean that you are using m4 to generate C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% percent sure if this is what you're after but this makes `__file__` to output filename in quotes (on my mac os):

```
define(`_m4__file__',defn(`__file__'))
pushdef(`__file__',`"_m4__file__"')

define(`_m4__line__',defn(`__line__'))
pushdef(`__line__',`"_m4__line__"')

define(`echo',`$*')
echo(__file__,__line__)
echo(__file__,__line__)
```

output:

```
"m4.t","8"
"m4.t","9"
```

for single quotes use a bit more escaping:

```
define(`_m4__file__',defn(`__file__'))
pushdef(`__file__',`''`_m4__file__'`'')

define(`_m4__line__',defn(`__line__'))
pushdef(`__line__',`''`_m4__line__'`'')

define(`echo',`$*')
echo(__file__,__line__)
echo(__file__,__line__)
```

outputs:

```
'm4.t','8'
'm4.t','9'
```

Comment: I think this may be it. However how about single quotes?